# How to write a Cron Job to execute simple php script?

Tags: php, syntax, cron

I have a simply php script on my server and want it to be run every 2 minutes using a cron job.

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   http://mydomain.com/_adder.php
```

I suspect the command syntax is wrong.

Do I need to add a command before the script url? Another way to run the script?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of a URL, you need to put the path to the file

Comment: @Paco not just the path to *a file*, but the path to some *executable* (often a script-file)

Comment: I assumed that the php file would be *executable*

Answer (score 2):

the cron-job will simply execute a program on the (local) machine.

**a URL is *NOT* a program.** it's a link to a ressource.

whether this ressource triggers a PHP-script execution is not of cron's business.

in any case, you could run a cron-job that will periodically *visit* a given URL. e.g. using the `wget` command (a "non-interactive web-page downloader")

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   wget --quiet -O /dev/null http://mydomain.com/_adder.php
```

Comment: I think the user wants to execute a script on his own machine

Comment: @Paco probably; he is a bit contradictory here ("my server" vs giving a public URL)

Comment: @Paco... by my sever, I mean a public URL that I connect to via FTP. When the URL is loaded the script runs automatically.

Comment: @user586011 in any case, regardless of `http` or `ftp` the solution provided will "load" the script and thus trigger it's execution

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as umläute suggest, but being a local file it's actually faster to access from command line php like this:

```
*/2 * * * * php /path/to/file/_adder.php
```

there are differences running a script from the command line vs via a browser that may effect the script.

you may need the full path to php on some systems

Comment: website.com/path/_adder.php is the direct path to the script

Comment: starting with / it should be the full server file path, but i have no way of knowing what that is in your case

Comment: @user586011 you *cannot* run a script via php that is located on a remote server. URLs starting with `http://` or `ftp://` are *always* considered on a *remote* server as you can only access them via the network - even if the machine is physically the same as the one you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

use `php-cgi` to make GET request similar to a web browser .

```
/usr/bin/php-cgi   /your_path/_adder.php
```

if you're using Linux you can use `which php-cgi` to locate for php-cgi or search for `php7.2-cgi` if php `7.2` installed on your machine or search using different version . for Windows users search for `php-cgi.exe` .