# When time is midnight do a mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, updates

So I have a piece of code which is supposed to reset a message of the date (motd) at midnight, my aim is that once the time reached midnight (00:00:00 GMT) that it resets the message of the day back to its original state. So far i have tried the following:

```
if (gmdate('H:i:s') === '00:00:00') { mysql_query(//execute code) }
```

all suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: forgot to mention my website is hosted from a webhost called nitrousnetworks not localhost. will this affect anything?

Edit-2: found a cron job section in cPanel X. i've set it to run every 24h at midnight but what do i put in the `Command:` section?

Edit-3: Thankyou all, i believe i have got it now :)

Comment: I would strongly suggest a cron job.  I would also strongly suggest top stop using `mysql_*` functions and use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: ^ Exactly, you can set up an @daily cron job. Now it runs at midnight every night already, no need to perform checks in php as well.

Comment: Cronjob is what you are looking for.

Comment: Using [MySQL  Events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) could be an option for you, without any need for PHP

Comment: hi all, thanks for your fast response, i am only a 15 year old coder so haven't really expanded out into languages other than the basics yet. nevertheless i will try using `cronjob` and feedback how it works. Also if you don't mind me asking, what is mysqli?

Comment: mysqli is an "improved" mysql library, that has fever (known) security holes. But foremost mysql_* lib is deprecated and will eventually stop working! mysqli also supports object oriented programming in a better way then mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'd suggest you use an cronjob/script for this.

On some hosts they have a function available for you to just set up a cronjob easily. Otherwise you could check up how to do it yourself - if needed.

[How to write a Cron Job to execute simple php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212322/how-to-write-a-cron-job-to-execute-simple-php-script)
[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Edit; Also like someone commented, use mysqli rather than mysql.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reponse. also thankyou for the links, i believe i have a small understanding of cronjobs now. however how would i make it execute at 00:00:00?

Answer (score 1):

Just so you have an alternative of the strongly suggested `cron` triggered `php` scrip, here's an other solution: you can set up a [MySQL scheduled event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html)

```
CREATE EVENT reset_motd
ON SCHEDULE AT '2014-03-25 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
DO UPDATE ...
```

Of course, this is only a solution if you have all you inputs in the database available for the defined event.

Answer (score 1):

the best solution for this kind of task is probably a Cron Job

The problem with your solution is that it depends on a user visiting your site exactly 00:00:00. Witch is a quite bad design.

One other solution would be to have it reset the message when the first user after midnight is visiting your site.

One example would be Like this:

```
<?php
   $today = new DateTime("today");
   $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM firstVisit WHERE date='" . $today->format("Ymd") "'");

   if($result->num_rows == 0){
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO firstVisit (`date`) VALUES('" . $today->format("Ymd") . "')");

        //Do your update
   }
?>
```